# What is access control of an Amazon EC2 instance like if people purchase AMI from marketplace?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm new to the Amazon EC2 platform and marketplace, so I need some help with the questions I have.

Currently our company is trying to create a customized Linux AMI to put into marketplace, and I'm responsible for setting up the whole thing. I'm not quite sure about the following things when customers load one new instance:

Do they have the access to the Linux system that we pre-configured when they get the instance? I don't know how is the instance look like to the customer after they purchase it, but we want to protect the settings of the instance from being modified by customers, we only want them to use the web interface through port 443(https).

How is the security group applied for the new instance? Are the customers responsible for setting up the firewall rules or is the security group bound to the instance when I create the AMI?

By default the instance does not have any public IP addresses, and currently I have to manually fetch an Elastic IP address and hook it to the instance. Is this the responsibility of the customer when they load an instance?

Comment: If you don't want to allow customers to have an control, its probably best if you launch the instance for them.

Comment: @datasage: I think you are right, I just realized that from Mike's answer. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AMI is just a disk image. It will be fully on the customer to make security group configs, apply elastic IP's etc.

In fact, if you are trying to use HTTPS, the end customer will also need to be able to install their own certificate on the instance.

The user would typically have full access to the system and be able to do anything to it that you are not able to specifically disallow through your own customizations to the system.

Comment: Thanks for answer. One more question: does amazon ec2 provide any password based ssh authentication(I guess not)?